# ffmpeg: Container Change MKV to MP4 Streams: 1 Video, 2 Audio, 1 Subtitle, 1 Attachment

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-conversion, subtitles, attachments

I'm changing containers from MKV to MP4. I think I'm close, but I can't figure out how to keep the Subtitle and Attachment (font for the subtitles) streams.

Stream 0  Video (H264) - Stream 1  Audio (mp4a) - Stream 2  Audio (mp4a) - Stream 3  Subtitles (ssa) - Stream 4  Attachment (tff)

I've tried a lot of variations, but most recently these 3:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -c copy -c:s mov_text output.mp4
```

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s -map 0:t -c copy output.mp4
```

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -c copy -c:s copy -c:t copy output.mp4
```

I wind up with the video stream and the 2 audio streams only.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.

- MP4 only supports "mov_text" subtitles. Player support for such subs is hit-and-miss.
- MP4 will not accept your attachment.